# Long press on custom checkbox

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, checkbox, react-native

I'm trying to create a long-press handler on the checkbox. The package with  the component is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-checkbox — i think it is default one. The problem is that checkbox intercepts `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` events and my `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component doesn't emit anything. Here is the code:

```
    var pressStart = 0;
    const pressTimeout = 400;

    function pressIn() {
        alert(0);

        pressStart = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    }

    function pressOut() {
        var pressEnd = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        if (pressEnd - pressStart < pressTimeout) return;

        alert(1);
    }

    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={pressIn} onPressOut={pressOut}>
                <View>
                    {/*<Text>asdasdasd</Text>*/}
                    <CheckBox checked={this.state.done} labelStyle={style.checkbox} label={this.state.name} onChange={toggleChecked} />
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    );
```

Also, if i use `Text` component instead of `CheckBox` — it fires `pressIn` event, but `pressOut` doesn't work (i see `alert(0)`, but not `alert(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at first, i've created a fork from the `react-native-checkbox` package that supports `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` events: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-checkbox-touch-events

But I think it will be useless, cause you can do some like this (I don't promise it works):

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback delayPressIn={0} onPressIn={pressIn} onPressOut={pressOut}>
    <View>
        <CheckBox onPress={press} />
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Anyway, I will use my package, I'm too lazy to test this solution and don't want to get disappointed with my work.

And also: don't divide `getTime()` by 1000, if you want milliseconds...